# Captive portal login with facebook Safari pop up window

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've built a captive portal for some routers I've configured with a Radius server, so when a customer tries to login, they're faced with a login screen (think McDonalds situation)... Facebook being one of the options to login with.

This all works on Google Chrome, the problem is with Safari.

Safari on Mac or iPhone I've learnt tries to reach http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html and if it doesn't return the word "success" Apple/Safari then knows it's a captive portal situation so tries to help out by popping up a (Safari) window where you can login.

My problem is that Facebook has some popup's of it's own, and these aren't working in Safari's popup window (they work through Safari's main browser):

1. If you're not logged in, Facebook will popup a login to Facebook window.
2. If you are logged in with Facebook, but the App is not authorised, a pop up will show asking you to click OK and check permissions to authorise.

I've overcome point 1, by instead redirecting the user to the Facebook login window that can return back to my website, but I've not overcome point 2.

Here's how I've overcome point 1.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  //statusChangeCallback(response);
  var uri = encodeURI('MY WEBSITE');
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        location.reload();
    } else if(response.status === 'unknown') {
        window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1543071895971445&redirect_uri="+uri+"&response_type=token");
    } else {
        //can't avoid the Facebook 'authorise app' popup that doesn't work on Apple captive portal popup.
        FBSignup();
    }
```

In the else statement above, FBSignup() calls the `FB.login` function that brings up the authorise popup.

Is there a way I can overcome point 2 by presenting the user with a method to authorise the app without a popup?  I'm also using the Facebook PHP SDK if something there can help?

Alternatively accepted answer would be to help me resolve why I the Facebook popups don't work in the captive portal assistant that apple brings up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the PHP v5.0 SDK to instead generate a Facebook URL to redirect the user to, which doesn't bring any popups, so is Apple captive-portal friendly.  You can also request permissions through this redirect, here's how.

```
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => fbappid,
      'app_secret' => fbappsecret,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location', 'user_hometown', 'user_relationships']; // Optional permissions

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/urbanportal/wifilogin.php?origlink='.$_SESSION['origlink'].'&routerlink='.$_SESSION['routerlink'].'&siteid='.$_SESSION['siteid'], $permissions);
```